# python Blackjack Graphics Game - my card image won't import

Tags: python, blackjack

I'm making a Blackjack game and still early process. When I run my program, I get the error 
`im = Image(Point(350, 250), "playingcards/" + suit + str(rank) + ".gif")
NameError: name 'suit' is not defined`
Which I'm pretty sure it's because im = ___ is in my def main(): part of my function, even though the suit is being defined within my code.

It's basically seems like my program is ignoring all of my code and going straight to the def main(), which is probably an ordering error on my part, but can someone explain where it's supposed to go so that it reads all my class functions before the main?

Here's my code:

```
from random import *
from graphics import *

class PlayingCard:

    def __init__(self, rank, suit):
       self.rank = rank
       self.suit = suit

    def getRank (self):
        return self.rank

    def getSuit(self):
        return self.suit

    def BJValue (self):
        if self.rank == 'Ace':
            return 1
        elif self.rank == 'Jack' or self.rank == 'Queen' or self.rank == 'King':
            return 10
        else:
            return int(self.rank)

    def __str__(self):
        suit_name= {'S':'Spades', 'C':'Clubs', 'D':'Diamonds', 'H':'Hearts'}
        rank_name=[None, 'Ace','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','Jack','Queen','King']

        return '%s of %s' % (Card.rank_names[self.rank], Card.suit_names[self.suit])


from random import *
from playingcards import *

class Deck:

    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = []
        x = eval(input("How many cards shall be dealt?"))
        for suit in range(x):
            for rank in range(1, 14):
                card = Card(suit, rank)
                self.cards.append(card)

    def shuffle(self):
        random.shuffle(self.cards)


    def DealCard(self): 
        return self.deck.pop(0) 

    def CardsLeft(self): 
        return len(self.deck)

class Blackjack:

    def __init__(self, dHand=[], pHand=[]):
        self.dHand = PlayingCard
        self.pHand = PlayingCard
        self.deck = Deck()
        Deck.shuffle(self.Blackjack)

    def initDeal(self,gwin,xposD,yposD,xposP,yposP):
        self.DealCard.dHand = [2]
        self.DealCard.pHand = [2]
      #  PlayingCard.draw(win)

        dealtCard = self.deck.DealCard()

        suit = dealtCard.getSuit()
        rank = dealtCard.getRank()
        #import(file=image_



    def hit(self, gwin, xPos, yPos):
        print('hi')

    def evaluateHand(self, hand):
        print('hi')

    def dealerPlays(self, gwin, xPos, yPos):
        print('hi')



def main():
    win = GraphWin("BlackJack", 800, 800)
    im = Image(Point(350, 250), "playingcards/" + suit + str(rank) + ".gif")
    im.draw(win)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: You have to create an instance of each of your classes somewhere to use them.

Comment: @paisanco, so do i basically write `if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()` after each class?

And if so, do i keep it as __name__ or would it be for instance __PlayingCard__ == "__main__"

Comment: No, you only need  one main(). But you've got to code the logic of the game. In your Blackjack class you made a Deck instance, in your Deck  class you called Card (suit, rank) but your PlayingCard class has (rank,suit) in its init. Did you make a BlackJack instance in a function or class called GraphWin? It's not shown. Also in your main, the variable suit is not defined. You have variables named suit at class scope but not global scope. I think you need to condense your code to a MCVE that reproduces a specific error. We can't debug the whole app on SO, that's too broad.

Comment: You seem to be confused about some basic Python concepts such as variable scope and modules. You should read some documentation on these subjects.

Comment: @Cyb3rFly3r, in every def function, i have a self.___ = __ variable, which are my instance variables right?For instance, `def __init__(self, rank, suit):
       self.rank = rank
       self.suit = suit`

So I thought I do have instance variables throughout, and I still get the same error

Comment: That part is fine, but in your main function there is a reference to suit which is not in scope. In other words, main() is not a class method, is a module method and thus it has no way of knowing anything about your class instance variable.